# VSTS Error: SQLSQL71501: Computed Column: contains an unresolved reference to an object

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2017, database-project

I get the following error when building out my `databaseB` in my project. This database is referencing master, msdb as well as the other databases: `databaseA` and `databaseAsynonyms`.

`databaseB` uses synonyms (linked server) from `databaseA`.

The build returns the following error:

> SQL71501: Computed Column: [bi_tb_sales].[v_board_digital_inventory].[dim_panel_revenue_branch] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[bi_tb_sales_dim_panel].  [dim_panel_revenue_branch], [dbo].[bi_tb_sales_dim_panel].  [p]::[dim_panel_revenue_branch] or [dbo].[bi_tb_sales_dim_site].  [p]::[dim_panel_revenue_branch].

Screenshot:

[image]

I tried the following 6 fixes listed on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/152759ac-8f03-471c-b79c-49f605fe12ba/unresolved-references-and-synonyms?forum=ssdt) but it has not fixed the issue.

Any other suggestions?